# Как передать данные с input в html?

Tags: php

Как передать данные с input в html, который находится в переменной $content?

```
<form id='form_reviews'  method='post'>
  <input type='text' id='reviews_form_name' name='name' placeholder='Имя' value='' /><br>
  <input type='submit' id='button_form_reviews' value='Оставить свой отзыв' />
</form>
$content = "
<div class='card'>
    <span>/*Сюда должны передаваться данные с input*/</span>
</div>
";
```

Comment: Всмысле передаваться данные? После отправки формы или при наборе?

Comment: После щелчка по кнопке отправить

Comment: используйте ajax

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку и отправки в скрипт обработчик, ваши данные будут в `$_POST['name']`. Потом уж делайте с этими данными что хотите. И да, нужно добавить атрибут в форму (`<form>`) `action="your_file_script.php"`, например.